# Should I compile .so file using emcc to open it with dlopen()?

Tags: c, emscripten

I'm trying to open a dynamic library file (`.so`) using `dlopen()`.
So I created `libhello.so` file in Linux using `gcc` and compiled the `main.c` file with `--preload-file libhello.so` option.
However, I got the following error in a browser:

> (index):29 To use dlopen, you need to use Emscripten's linking support, see https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/wiki/Linking

Should I compile `.so` file using `emcc` instead of `gcc` in order to be used in a web browser?

reference: https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/files/packaging_files.html#preloading-files

Comment: can you share the file format of your .so file, it is 32 bit or 64 bit and stripped or non stripped. and what are the options you are using in your makefile to generate above .so file.

Comment: You want to load a x86 program from WebAssembly?

Comment: (that is about as possible as loading a .dylib file compiled for iPhone, from a Windows EXE)

Comment: Did you read the linked page? And did you follow its instructions?

Comment: @dragon I compiled it with `gcc -shared -o libhello.so -fPIC hello.c -ldl` in Ubuntu.

Comment: @ZackLee try this to genrate
 gcc -fpic -shared $(LDFLAGS) -Wl,-soname,$(SONAME) -o $@  $^  $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) -lrt -lpthread 
you can make your own version, and ignore the once's not needed like LDLIBS,LDFLAGS,lrt,lpthread.

Comment: @dragon Thank you but I just learned that I need to compile with `emcc` https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/11493